# SFMC Microsite - Server not found

Tags: marketing-cloud, microsites

I am playing with Microsites on Salesforce Marketing Cloud and for some reasons, on one of the Business Units I have, the Microsite page always returns "Server not found".

I understand, that issue could be on our side but I was wondering if it was possible to change the base URL of the Microsite instead of using the http://pages.[mail_website] one?

On another Business Unit it is using http://pages.s7.exacttarget.com which could be fine for now.

Any clues?

Cheers,
Seb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Server Not Found` indicates you may not have added your Microsite under Interactions (and started it).

I believe a custom domain comes with the [Sender Authentication Package](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/sender_authentication_package/).

Comment: Thanks Adam for the info.

The Microsite is started and the page is published so that's not the issue here.

I think you're right it's the Sender Authentification Package but probably our [DNS configuration](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/sender_authentication_package/maintaining_your_own_dns_records_for_your_sending_domain/) that is not right... I was hoping to avoid having to chase the sysadmins for that :)